# Set value in frames JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set value if input is in frame's.

```
<iframe id="main_frame_first" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" name="main_frame">
<iframe id="main_frame_second" name="main" width="100%" height="100%" data-par="" class=" ">
<input name="_filter[head]" type="text" size="20" maxlength="60" style="width:100%">
</iframe>
</iframe>
```

it should be somethink like

$('#main_frame_first').contents().find('#main_frame_second').contents().find('#????').val('myValue');

Comment: For starters are both of these frames on same domain as the current page? If not you can't get inside them due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: @charlietfl, I do not know. How to check are they on the same domain?

Comment: inspect the url's used in `src` for them in browser dev tools

Comment: @charlietfl, they have different sources

Comment: Then you can't do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all these pages are on same domain you would need to listen to load event of each iframe in addition to targeting the correct input

Something like:

```
$('#main_frame_first').on('load', function(){
   // "this" is first iframe
   $(this).contents().find('#main_frame_second').on('load', function(){
        // "this" is second iframe
        $(this).contents().find('input[name="_filter[head]"]').val(newValue);
   });
});
```

You will be denied access if either of the iframes is from different origin than the main page